# Best way to check errorlevel

Tags: windows, batch-file, findstr, errorlevel

I am writing a batch script to be run in Win 10 OS. However I am facing issues with checking errorlevel of exist status of a Windows command. Faintly I decided to use below way:

```
findstr /I /C:"EXIT_FAILURE" /I /C:"UNKNOWN" file 
if '%ERRORLEVEL%'=='0' goto CHECKFAILED

findstr /I /C:"EXIT_SUCCESS" file 
if '%ERRORLEVEL%'!='0' goto CHECKFAILED

exit /B 0

:CHECKFAILED
exit /B 2
```

Is it the right way to check - I mean compare errorlevel as string or using within single quotes?

The errorlevel when validated for its numeric values leads to understanding considerations that command provides like:

```
if ERRORLEVEL 0
```

would mean TRUE for ERRORLEVEL >=0. Similarly there are other considerations.

Hence is it right to use ?& compare ERRORLEVEL as string as mentioned above?

Comment: No - that question states using ERRORLEVEL in IF command blocks

Comment: It varies by use case; there is no "right" or "wrong" way to check errorlevel, which means that any answer we give will be opinion-based. That said, double quotes are better for comparisons than single quotes.

Comment: Check `if /?`; `!=` isn't a valid comparator.

Comment: [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) answers your question, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach using conditional operators, `&&` and `||`. It is based upon your previous post, which appears to be related to the same question, *'the use of errorlevels'*.

The conditional operators work a little like:

- `&&`   'if the previous command succeeded'
- `||`   'if the previous command failed'.

```bat
@Echo Off
If "%~4"=="" Exit /B 1
If Not Exist "%~3" Exit /B 1
If Not Exist "%~2\%~1" Exit /B 1
If Not Exist "%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe" Exit /B 1

Set "arg1=%~1"
Set "logfile=%~3\%~4.%arg1:.=_%.res"

Copy /V /Y "%~2\%~1" "%logfile%" 1>NUL 2>&1 || Exit /B 1

Set "findstr=%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe"
Set "errno=0"

"%findstr%" /I "EXIT_FAILURE UNKNOWN" "%logfile%" 1>NUL 2>&1 && (Set "errno=2"
) || "%findstr%" /I "PASS" "%logfile%" 1>NUL 2>&1 || Set "errno=2"

Exit /B %errno%
```

So if the [findstr](/questions/tagged/findstr) command is successful, *i.e. at least one of the strings was matched*, it will perform the `set` command, *i.e. define an error number value*. If the `findstr` command failed, *i.e. neither string was matched*, the `set` command would also have failed to define an error number value, meaning that the second `findstr` command would be ran. If the second `findstr` command doesn't match the string, the error number value will be `set`, otherwise the default value of `0` would remain in place.